# Find point of intersection between two vectors in MATLAB

Tags: math, matlab

I have a very simple MATLAB question. What is the easiest way to find the point of intersection between two vectors. I am not familiar with the various MATLAB functions -- it seems like there should be one for this.

For example, if I have one vector from (0,0) to (6,6) and another vector from (0,6) to (6,0), I need to determine that they intersect at (3,3).

Comment: You should ask this on mathoverload.com

Comment: @Michael: I think you meant *mathoverflow.net*, although that site is geared more towards "research level mathematics". Simpler questions like this should probably stay on SO (see this Meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to-s)

Comment: Besides, this problem involves programming a solution into Matlab, not how to mathmatically solve the problem. See my answer for how to generally (for any data in any number of dimensions) solve this problem in Matlab.

Comment: Vectors don't have intersections, lines do!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution is to use the equations derived in [this tutorial for finding the intersection point of two lines in 2-D](https://web.archive.org/web/20091003070719/http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/) (**update:** this is an internet archive link since the site no longer exists). You can first create two matrices: one to hold the x coordinates of the line endpoints and one to hold the y coordinates.

```
x = [0 0; 6 6];  %# Starting points in first row, ending points in second row
y = [0 6; 6 0];
```

The equations from the above source can then be coded up as follows:

```
dx = diff(x);  %# Take the differences down each column
dy = diff(y);
den = dx(1)*dy(2)-dy(1)*dx(2);  %# Precompute the denominator
ua = (dx(2)*(y(1)-y(3))-dy(2)*(x(1)-x(3)))/den;
ub = (dx(1)*(y(1)-y(3))-dy(1)*(x(1)-x(3)))/den;
```

And you can now compute the intersection point of the two lines:

```
xi = x(1)+ua*dx(1);
yi = y(1)+ua*dy(1);
```

For the example in the question, the above code gives `xi = 3` and `yi = 3`, as expected. If you want to check that the intersection point lies *between* the endpoints of the lines (i.e. they are finite line *segments*), you just have to check that the values `ua` and `ub` both lie between 0 and 1:

```
isInSegment = all(([ua ub] >= 0) & ([ua ub] <= 1));
```

A couple more points from the tutorial I linked to above:

- If the denominator `den` is 0 then the two lines are parallel.
- If the denominator and numerator for the equations for `ua` and `ub` are 0 then the two lines are coincident.

Comment: Clean, precise and a good answer with some nice code. Wonderful!

Comment: Your code is wrong. Even though you say "put x coords in one matrix and y coords in another," you put each vector pair in a separate matrix. Thus x becomes one line (with row vectors), y another. The correct ua = (dx(1)*(x(1,2)-y(1,2))-dy(2)*(x(1)-y(1))) / den, and the yi = x(1,2) + ua*dx(2). I'm surprised nobody noticed.

Comment: @Algomorph: I think you've misunderstood a few things. The `x` and `y` matrices contain coordinates for each line organized column-wise, i.e. column 1 contains the starting and ending coordinates of line 1, etc. Also, I'm using linear indexing in my equations, so for example `x(3)` is equivalent to `x(1,2)`.

Comment: Can you tell me please, in the code, is the first line from [0 0]' to [6 6]'? In other words, isn't y_1 = 0, y_2 = 6, y_3 = 6, and y_4 = 0? Because in that case, y(1)-y(3) seems like it's actually x_3 - x_4 and x(1)-x(3) is actually x_1 - x_2...

Comment: Also, using homogeneous coordinates, couldn't we just do "intercept = cross(cross(v1,v2),cross(v3,v4)); interscept = intercept / intercept(3)"?

Answer (score 8):

Well, you really have two points on two different lines, and you want to find the intersection. The easiest way is to find the equations of the two lines and then calculate the intersection.

The equation of a line is given by *y = mx + b* where *m* is the slope and *b* is the y-intercept. For one line you have two points which gives two equations. So, you can solve for the constants *m* and *b*. This gives the following two equations:

```
 0 = 0*m + 1*b  % Using the first point x=y=0 into y=m*x+b
 6 = 6*m + 1*b  % Using the second point x=y=6
```

Or in matrix form:

```
 [ 0 ] = [ 0 1 ]* [ m ]
 [ 6 ]   [ 6 1 ]  [ b ]
```

For the first line the constants can be calculated in MATLAB by

```
 C1 = inv([0 1;6 1]*[1;0]; % m=C1(1) and b=C(2)
```

Now that you have the equation for the two lines you can solve for the intersection by solving the following system of equations (which are obtained by manipulating the equation for a line):

```
 m_1*x-y = -b_1
 m_2*x-y = -b_2
```

All that is left is to write the above system of equations in matrix form and solve:

```
 [x] = inv [m_1 -1] * [-b_1]
 [y]       [m_2 -1]   [-b_2]
```

Or in MATLAB syntax:

```
 I = inv([m_1 -1; m_2 -1])*[-b_1;-b_2]; % I is the intersection.
```

---

**Notes**

- As per gnovice's comment if the lines are actually line segments you need to check if the intersection is between the end points of the line segments.
- If the two slopes are equal, m_1 = m_2, then there will either be no intersection or infinitely many intersections.

Comment: One additional point: If the two lines are being treated as line *segments*, an additional check is needed to see if the intersection point lies within the end points of each line.

Comment: @Amro: can you explain why _inv_ should be avoided?

Comment: for AX=B, if A is square and invertible, then X = inv(A)*B is theoretically the same as X = A\B. But the computations involving the backslash operators are preferable because they require less computer time, less memory, and have better error-detection properties. Refer to http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f4-983672.html and http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f4-2224.html for more explanations

Answer (score 2):

For a general multi-dimensional solution, what you're actually doing is solving a series of linear systems.

First you need to reduce the equations to linear form: `Ax+By=C` (expand dimensions as necessary)

For two-points:

```
y - y1 = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x - x1)
y - y1 = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * x - (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * x1
(y1 - y2) / (x2 - x1) * x + y - y1 = (y1 - y2) / (x2 - x1) * x1
(y1 - y2) / (x2 - x1) * x + y = (y1 - y2) / (x2 - x1) * x1 + y1
(y1 - y2) * x + (x2 - x1) * y = (y1 - y2) * x1 + (x2 - x1) * y1

A = (y1 - y2)
B = (x2 - x1)
C = (y1 - y2) * x1 + (x2 - x1) * y1 = A * x1 + B * y1
```

For your example:

```
x1 = 0, x2 = 6, y1 = 0, y2 = 6
A1 = (0 - 6) = -6
B1 = (6 - 0) = 6
C1 = A1 * 0 + B1 * 0 = 0

x1 = 0, x2 = 6, y1 = 6, y2 = 0
A2 = (6 - 0) = 6
B2 = (6 - 0) = 6
C2 = A2 * 0 + B2 * 6 = 6 * 6 = 36
```

Then, form a matrix, with A B and C in rows:

```
[A1 B1 C1]
[A2 B2 C2]

[-6 6 0]
[ 6 6 36]
```

Now reduce to reduced echelon form using the Matlab function `rref(matrix)`:

```
[ 1 0 3]
[ 0 1 3]
```

As you can guess, the last column is your intersection point. This is expandable to as many dimensions as necessary. If your reduced echelon form has something other than the identity matrix for the front part of it, your vectors either do not have a unique intersection point, or have no intersection point, depending on the form of the matrix.

```
dim = 2;

% Do other stuff, ending with rref(matrix)

if (matrix(:,1:dim) == eye(dim))
    % Matrix has unique solution.
    solution = (matrix(:,dim+1))'
else
    % No unique solution.
end
```

In two dimensions, the variations are:

Linear solution, indicating solution is a line of form `x + By = C`:

```
[ 1 B C]
[ 0 0 0]
```

No solution, indicating the lines do not cross, where `C2 <> 0`:

```
[ 1 B C1]
[ 0 0 C2]
```

Answer (score 2):

The other results are confusing, verbose and incomplete, IMO. So here's my two cents - also potentially confusing and verbose.

If you are sure that your lines are not skew-parallel or parallel, the following is all you need:

```
% Let each point be def as a 3x1 array
% Let points defining first line be  : p1, q1
% Let points defining second line be : p2, q2

L = p1-p2;
M = p1-q1;
N = p2-q2;
A = [M N];
T = pinv(A)*L;
h = p1-T(1)*(p1-q1); % h is a 3x1 array representing the actual pt of intersection
```

Yeah, the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) is a powerful thing. The explanation for the approach is: You want to find the weights or the scaling factors of the 'direction vectors' (M and N are direction vectors), that linearly combine M and N to give L.

A full description is presented below. It presents a simple exception detection scheme, and their handling is left to the user. (The minimum distance between two line algorithms is from Wikipedia; the comparison of direction cosines (DCS) to check vector attitudes is common knowledge.)

```
% Let each point be def as a 3x1 array
% Let points defining first line be : p1, q1
% Let points defining second line be: p2, q2

% There are two conditions that prevent intersection of line segments/lines
% in L3 space. 1. parallel 2. skew-parallel (two lines on parallel planes do not intersect)
% Both conditions need to be identified and handled in a general algorithm.

% First check that lines are not parallel, this is done by comparing DCS of
% the line vectors
% L, M, N ARE DIRECTION VECTORS.
L = p1-p2;
M = p1-q1;
N = p2-q2;

% Calculate a normalized DCS for comparison. If equal, it means lines are parallel.
MVectorMagnitude = sqrt(sum(M.*M,2)); % The rowsum is just a generalization for N-D vectors.
NVectorMagnitude=sqrt(sum(N.*N,2)); % The rowsum is just a generalization for N-D vectors.

if isequal(M/MVectorMagnitude,N/NVectorMagnitude) % Compare the DCS for equality
     fprintf('%s\n', 'lines are parallel. End routine')
end;

% Now check that lines do not exist on parallel planes
% This is done by checking the minimum distance between the two lines. If there's a minimum distance, then the lines are skew.

a1 = dot(M,L); b1 = dot(M,M); c1 = dot(M,N);
a2 = dot(N,L); b2 = dot(N,M); c2 = dot(N,N);

s1 = -(a1*c2 - a2*c1)/(b1*c2-b2*c1);
s2 = -(a1*b2 - a2*b1)/(b1*c2-b2*c1);

Sm = (L + s1*M - s2*N);
s = sqrt(sum(Sm.*Sm,2));

if ~isequal(s,0) % If the minimum distance between two lines is not zero, then the lines do not intersect
    fprintf('%s\n','lines are skew. End routine')
end;

% Here's the actual calculation of the point of intersection of two lines.
A = [M N];
T = pinv(A)*L;
h = p1-T(1)*(p1-q1); % h is a 3x1 array representing the actual pt of intersection.
```

So the pinv approach will give you results even when your M and N vectors are skew (but not parallel, because inv(A'.A) is required to exist). You can use this to determine the minimum distance between two parallel lines or between two parallel planes - to do this, define `k = p2+T(2)*(p2-q2)`, and then the required distance is h-k. Also note that h and k are the points on the lines that are closest to each other IFF lines are skew.

So the use of the pseudoinverse and projection spaces gives us a concise algorithm for:

1. Determining the point of intersection of two lines (not parallel, and not skew)
2. Determining the minimum distance between two lines (not parallel)
3. Determining the points closest to each other on two skew lines.

Concise is not the same as time-efficient. A lot depends on your exact pinv function implementation - MATLAB uses `svd` which solves to a tolerance. Also, some results will only be approximately accurate in higher dimensions and higher order definitions of the measurement metric (or vector norms). Besides the obvious dimension independent implementation, this can be used in statistical regression analysis and algebraically maximizing likelihood of point estimates.