# Google map API checking if passed through polygon line

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Here is my problem.

I am using Google maps API and am calculating the distance between a from and to point. This is fine. I also have an array of polygon lines which indicate in this case the Greater London area. I can work out if my destination is within the polygons without an issue. But what I can't work out is at what point I crossed the poly line (if that makes sense). The reason I need to know is the calculate the distance between the final destination and the entry point of the polygon, This is because the rate per mile for the bus journey is more expensive within the Greater London area as opposed to the rest of the UK.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=intersection%20of%20line%20and%20polygon)?

Comment: you need to find an interval in your from-to path that intersects a line in your polygon. this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050850/matlab-find-point-of-intersection-between-two-vectors